# Troun / troundu

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, littérature

Bonjour,

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois* II :

> tout s'est envolé en même temps ! et les ailes du moulin avec ! si je
> les ai vues filer les ailes du moulin au ciel ! et les cannes à Jules
> ! et la famille Lutry entière ! **troun** de l'air ! **troundu** la Rirette !
> en même temps ! bataclan !

Savez-vous ce que signifie *troun* / *troundu* ici ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Troun de l'air* est un juron provençal. Qu'on peut trouver, entre autres, dans Alexandre Dumas.

> « Troun de l’air ! » s’écria Caderousse — (Alexandre Dumas, *Le Comte de Monte-Cristo*)

Le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/troun_de_l%E2%80%99air) nous dit que c'est la contraction de *tonnerre de l'air*. En effet, en provençal *tonnerre* se dit *tron*. On peut lire sur le site de l'Office du tourisme de [Salon de Provence](https://www.visitsalondeprovence.com/les-incontournables/lart-de-vivre-en-provence/la-langue-provencale2/les-boutades/) :

> **Tron** : Tonnerre. Souvent utilisé dans l’expression « tron de l’air » désignant la plupart du temps une femme active, énergique et enjouée, mais qui peu aussi signifier « la foudre » « Que le tron de l’air te cure ! » « Cette femme, c’est un vrai tron de l’air »

Céline a fait *troundu* à partir de *troun de l'air*, la reprise servant à évoquer le rythme d'une chanson, faisant suite à *turlututu la Tontaine* juste avant, et suivi de *la Rirette* qui évoque une vieille chanson paillarde.